# overlapping Image and Grid Flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to put a grid over an svg but when the dimensions of the screen change my image go to the bottom and my grid to the top how can i do to maintain the grid inside the svg when the screen change and how can i fix the grid vertically and horizontally

that's the code

```
void main() {
  runApp(RunMyApp());
}

class RunMyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RunMyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Grid with Right Bar')),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 6.0,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,       
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/scavi.svg',
                    semanticsLabel: 'My SVG Image',
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: bigGrid(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}

GridView bigGrid() {
  return GridView.count(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    crossAxisCount: 20,
    children: List.generate(
      20,
      (index) {
        return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: full screen]
[image: screen of the phone]
[image: sandbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Positioned` widget has some other properties. Such as `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom`, etc. Use `MediaQuery` to set the right position of your widget based on screen size.

```
Positioned.fill(
  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2, //example - customize it yourself
  child: bigGrid(),
),
```

//Updated new answer. use `AspectRatio` widget to maintain the aspect ratio of its child to fit it within the available space.

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Grid with Right Bar')),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 6.0,
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio:
                    16 / 9, // You can adjust the aspect ratio as needed
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                       'assets/scavi.svg',
                       semanticsLabel: 'My SVG Image',
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: bigGrid(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: i have tried to modify the values top,bottom ecc  but it seems doesn't work sir, i've updated the image to see what's happen thank you for the help

Comment: I saw your code and you didn't add the exact property on the Positioned widget.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to adjust the bigGrid() with the SVG?

Comment: i want a grid over the svg that is responsive i need a grid cause i have to click every grid item i need something like the image i add take a look

Comment: I've updated my code. Try that.

Comment: for the good of god thank you so much why with AspectRatio it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255018/discussion-between-ashikul-islam-sawan-and-drmain).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the `crossAxisCount` and the `count` values of `Grid.count` and `List.generate` respectively using MediaQuery? Try the following:

```
    GridView bigGrid() {
  return GridView.count(
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 55 ? 100 : 10,//Change this to your screen size's preference
    children: List.generate(
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 55 ? 9000 : 900, //Change this to your screen size's preference
      (index) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
```

Comment: i'm sorry but your solution didn't work i won't downvote despite try to update your  code the problem still remain (when the screen get smaller the image goes to the bottom and the grid goes to the top

Comment: Understood, thanks! Will try to come up with something